# roslaunch for ros 2 composition packages

Tags: ros, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was going trough the composition packages in ROS 2 which I found to be similar to the ros nodelets concepts.In ROS 1 we use launch files to start a particular nodelet.Will there be similar concept for  future ROS 2 releases? Or should we create a seperate executable like the manual_composition.cpp file for every components we have created in ROS 2 ??

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284492/roslaunch-for-ros-2-composition-packages/) by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to use something like `roslaunch` to run your nodes in ROS 2 without making a file like `manual_composition.cpp` each time. In the same demo is `api_composition.cpp` which loads nodes dynamically from a ROS service call:

https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/composition/src/api_composition.cpp

We'll have something similar to that, but exactly what and how it works is still under consideration. If you're interested see this design document:

https://github.com/ros2/design/pull/163

Which is still not finished yet, but already covers some of what you're asking about in the "calling conventions" section.

Also, see this which is a more "aspirational" demo of how node composition might work:

https://github.com/wjwwood/ros_cmake_auto_examples

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0